# Creating multiple CanvasJS charts inside <div> with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, canvasjs

I am trying to create multiple CanvasJS charts inside a div.

The div expects array of data from controller, loops through it(using ng-repeat) and displays the data in various controls.

Now when I try to put a CanvasJS Chart inside this div, the chart does not render and the error I see is 'chart with id  is not found'

But the same chart works well just outside this div.

Sample code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DTheWebDev/mozfsxpc/7/

APP.JS

```
var m = {
  "India": "2",
  "Australia": "3"
};

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = m;
}
var dps = [{
  x: 1,
  y: 10
}]; //dataPoints. 

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Live Data"
  },
  axisX: {
    title: "Axis X Title"
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "Units"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps
  }]
});

chart.render();
var xVal = dps.length - 1;
var yVal = 15;
var updateInterval = 1000;

var updateChart = function() {
  yVal = yVal + Math.round(5 + Math.random() * (-5 - 5));
  dps.push({
    x: xVal,
    y: yVal
  });
  xVal--;
  chart.render();

};
setInterval(function() {
  updateChart()
}, updateInterval);
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Match Summary:</h3>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(country,goals) in items">
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <h2>{{country}}: {{goals}} </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried to search with similar problem, but no luck.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow of the program should be taken care of. It throws the error 'Chart with ID is not found' as chart is tried to being rendered on a div element which doesn't exist yet.
Also, the ids of different div elements should be different.
You can use code similar to this to append dynamic id.

```
<div ng-repeat="(country,goals) in items"> 
    <div id="chartContainer-{{country}}" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
<h2>{{country}}: {{goals}} </h2>
</div>
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/mozfsxpc/)

Comment: Thanks @Rishabh.
In actual scenario, the data is populated in controller, using $http.get and the same is used in view as:

`<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController as vm">
        <div ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
            <div id="chartContainer{{user.Id}}" ></div>
        </div>
 </div>`

Now In my controller, though I have resolved the 'promise', still when the DOM reaches this point there is nothing in vm.users and it cant create div and give same error  'Chart with ID is not found'. Would appreciate your guidance on this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe again this is the issue of the flow of the program. The flow should be handled in such a way that the controller data is populated before trying to  create the div elements, and after this is taken care of, charts should be rendered. Also, here is a link explaining integration of CanvasJS with AngularJS: http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/05/29/angularjs-charts-with-canvasjs/. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rishabh for your guidance and answering my question. Your first answer solved the original problem asked. 
The second issue, I asked, was about the flow of program and after fixing it, everything worked fine for the charts.
Cheers

Comment: Glad to be of help, Deepak.